# Sort all files by numeric name and save

Tags: bash, command-line, sort

There is a lot of questions about sorting files by numeric, but non of them shows how to save the change. I have a directory containes 4 files - `0.txt,1.txt,3.txt,2.txt` and I want to sort the directory to be organized by numeric, from low to high.

```
$ ls
0.txt
1.txt
3.txt
2.txt
$ # command to sort dir
$ ls
0.txt
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

Comment: `ls` displays in alphanumeric name order as far as I know, I need to use the `-U` flag in order to show them in directory order. Is your `ls` aliased?

Comment: you can't sort the data itself. you can only sort a view. `ls` is such a view (sorted). another view is `find` (unsorted)

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use an alias, this will fix your problem:

cd

vim .bashrc

#At the bottom add the following line #

alias ls='ls -ls --color=auto'

#save and quit

source .bashrc

then "ls" will always display in a list and sorted.